# Hover effect is under the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

So I'm struggling with hover effect. The black box is the image and I want the red mask color (which has the same width and height) to be placed in front of the black box whenever user will hover on that image, I cannot do this because it seems the effect is under the image whenever I hover mouse on that image....
[image]

```css
.third-effect .mask {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 100px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  width: 274px;
  height: 197px;
}
.third-effect a.info {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
}
.third-effect:hover .mask {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 100px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.third-effect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<section class="module content">
  <div class="view third-effect">
    <img src="images/chronos.png" />
    <div class="mask">
      <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">Full Image</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please post your coding :)

Comment: if you are using absolute positioning then add `z-index:10` to the style of your mask.

Comment: you should not post answers, if you get any further in solving the problem you shoud update it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you can use the `:hover` selector to modify the style of your element when your mouse hovers it.

Take a look at this example to see how you can use it.
http://jsfiddle.net/wof159fh/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.third-effect .mask {

   opacity: 0;
   overflow:visible;
   border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
   width:274px;
   height:197px;


}

.third-effect a.info {
   position:relative;
   top:-10px;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
   transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out; }

.third-effect:hover .mask  {
   opacity: 1;
   border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

}


.third-effect:hover a.info {
 opacity:1;
 -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 -ms-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<section class="module content">


<div class="view third-effect">  
<img src="images/chronos.png" >
  <div class="mask">  
    <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">Full Image</a>  
 
  </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you want the overlaid div to be clickable or what.  You can use javascript to set stuff up.   So you can add a transparent color to the "hover" which would mask it in some color.   ex:  set opacity 0.8 with red.

Also there is the approach i did.  http://jsfiddle.net/kv0fsLs2/

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="hover"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
#image {
    background-color:red;
}
#hover {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: blue;
}
div > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#outer {
    position:relative;
    left: 250px;
    top: 250px;
}
```

this way you can tie a click handler to the overlaid div, if you didnt want to do it to the actual item.

Edit:  Here you can see it using opacity....  http://jsfiddle.net/kv0fsLs2/1/  All you would need to do is have the image be there instead of a red background as i did in the simplest of examples.

Edit 2:   Here is another fiddle, actually using an image: http://jsfiddle.net/kv0fsLs2/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```css
#image {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
  width: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}
#image:hover {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="image"></div>
```